# ajax json decode mysql fetch array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM order_list");

$test = array();
$i=0;

$myjsons = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo $myjsons[] = json_encode(array($row));
}
```

and a AJAX javascript

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser is too old to run me!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("resultTXT").value = eval("    (" + ajaxRequest.responseText + ")");
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "userfind.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}​
```

the javascript function wont store the array into the textbox

can anyone tell me whats the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: `echo $myjsons[] = json_encode(array($row));` What are you expecting from this to do?

Comment: You are building something in PHP that isn't going to be valid JSON. Accumulate it into an array: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $myjsons[] = $row; }` Then encode as JSON and output it: `echo json_encode($myjsons);`

Comment: what does it prints on console.log ajaxRequest.responseText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
     $myjsons[] = json_encode(array($row));
    }
 echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

instead of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
  echo $myjsons[] = json_encode(array($row));
}
```

you can use jquery library for tha ajax call  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post('userfind.php', function(data) {
   $("#resultTXT").val(data);// ==document.getElementById("resultTXT").value =data;
},'json'

);
```

Comment: my next problem will be to evaluate the string and generate a JavaScript generated table LOOOL

Answer (score 1):

JSON output would be invalid in your example, build the array and out put a single json encoded array like so:

```
$myjsons = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $myjsons[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

Comment: Thanks I have got the array parsed in javascript, I will have to go on to the next step generating the dynamic table